# Proving that $f(n)=nlog(n)$ is a $b$-smooth function

Tags: logarithms, smooth-functions

First I start with the definition: a function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ is b-smooth for an integer $b \geq 2$ if $f$ is eventually non decreasing and if
$$ \exists c \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \forall n \geq n_0 \hspace{1cm} f(b*n) \leq c*f(n)$$

The function is smooth if the b-smoothness holds for all integers $b \geq 2$.

Now I need to prove that $f(n)=n*log(n)$ is b-smooth for all $b \geq 2$.

I started like this

$f(b*n)=bn*log(bn) \leq c*n*log(n)$

$bn*log(bn) \leq c*n*log(n)$

I could divide both sides by n then 
$b*log(bn) \leq c*log(n)$
now

$\frac{log(bn)}{log(n)} \leq \frac{b}{c}$
with the rules of logarithm I can write it as
$\frac{log(bn)}{log(n)}=log_{n}(bn) \leq \frac{b}{c}$

But how can I show that the function is bounded by $\frac{b}{c}$ ? Maybe my steps were completely wrong

Comment: Note that $\log_n(bn) = \log_n(b) + \log_n(n)$, which is bounded for increasing $n$.

Comment: So "smoothness" here has nothing to do with differentiability or even continuity? I'd use another word.

Comment: @GregMartin: I completely agree! I also only know the concept of smoothness in regards to differentiability. So I was confused why b-smoothness is named/defined like this. Does this type of characteristics have another name in literature? I could not find anything under b-smoothness nowhere?

Comment: @hardmath: thank you, but how can I show that this is bounded for increasing n? Is it a characteristics of logarithm that I am missing?

Comment: Remember that $b$ is fixed for the purpose of your demonstration that $f$ is $b$-smooth.  Then $\log_n(b) \le \log_n(n) = 1$ for all $n\ge b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take $n_0=b$ and $c=2b$.  Then, since $\log$ is increasing:
$$
\implies \log(b)\leq \log(n)
$$
$$
\implies bn\log(b)\leq bn\log(n)
$$
$$
\implies bn\log(b)+bn\log(n)\leq bn\log(n)+bn\log(n)
$$
$$
\implies bn\log(bn)\leq 2bn\log(n)
$$

Comment: Thank you! So for c>2 the "smoothness" is fulfilled, right?

Comment: No, in my proof $c$ depends on $b$.  In particular, $c=2b$.